# Multi-threaded synchronization of shared model in project

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency

I am writing right now a multi-threaded application (game to be precise) as a hobby/research project. I have lately run into a really "simple" problem, which is making synchronization between threads (if it matters a lot to you, it's in c++).

My main issue is — I try to learn good design, and mutexing my whole model everywhere I can, is (in my opinion) resource wasteful, and just plainly asking for problems in further development. I have thought about making the whole process of synchronization transaction-based, but I feel it just does not fit the game type required performance/extensibility. I am new to concurrent programming, and I am here to learn something new about patterns specific to concurrent programming.

Some words about current design:

- MVC approach
- Online synchronization is being handled by a separate agent, which is identical on slave-client and master-server and is being handled separately from any server logic
- Database like structure is being synced undependably from server logic and has some minor subscription/observer pattern build in to notify controllers about changes.

*Notes*

- I do not look for documentation specific pieces of information (if they are not directly connected to performance or design), I know my `cppreference`,
- I do look for some extensive blog post/websites which can teach me some more about concurrent design patterns,
- I do want to know If I am just plainly doing things wrong (not in the wrong order, though).

**EDIT**

Like Mike has mentioned, I did not ask the question:

1) What are the best design patterns/norms which can be used in concurrent programming (Mostly usable in my case),

2) What are the biggest no-goes when it comes to concurrent programming performance.

Comment: Hmm, hard to tell without knowing which parts of the code you are mutexing. Is it just the interactions between the model, view and controller or are there more threads which access data concurrently? For the MVC part, you could take a look at the Active Object pattern or Command pattern which decouple method execution from its invokation.

Comment: I am using the decorator pattern on objects because I am using Flatbuffers for serializing data. I added a mutator/accessor decorator to every object and mutexed it inside of it. As for now (Work did not go that far, as I noticed a lot of code smell, like a ton of mutexes and repeatable logic connected with it). Next, I know for sure that I have one network-manager, which collects data from socket-managers, and tries to put it inside of the info-model. Then there are server controllers, which do their thing (like pathfinding, tick handling, etc.) and then aswell try to update info-model.

Comment: and here comes my main issue, which is how to handle the server work, to not run into typical races or working on not updated data.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting from a bit of a mistaken idea.  Parallelism is about performance, concurrency is about correctness.  A concurrent system isn't necessarily the fastest solution.  A *good* concurrent system minimizes and explicitly defines dependencies; enabling a robust, reactive system with minimal latency.  In contrast, a parallel system seeks to minimize its execution time by maximizing its utilization of resources; in doing so, it might maximize latency.   There is overlap, but the mindset is quite different.

There are many good concurrent languages.  C++ isn't one of them.  That said, you can write good concurrent systems in any language.  Most concurrent languages have a strong message passing bias, but good message passing libraries are available to most languages.

Message passing is a distinct from low level synchronization mechanism in that it is a model or way of thinking in and of itself.   Mutexes, semaphores, etc... are not.  They are tools, and should likely be ignored until the design is reasonably complete.

The design phase should be more abstract than synchronization mechanisms. Ideally, it should thresh out the operations (or transactions, if you prefer) and the necessary interactions between them.  From that schema, choices about how to arrange data and code for concurrent access should be natural.  If it isn't, your schema is incomplete.

Comment: Okay, while I do agree with you, I took my sweet time, to test my code with disassembly and answered my question somehow. Unfortunatly, even though your answer is leading in good direction I do not think it answers my question. Although definitly presented `parallelism` and `concurrency` in really easy to understand way for me, which I thank you for!